# I want to create pages through my selection of components

Tags: inno-setup

I saw this code that does almost what I need. 
It creates a page after you select the component, where I can select the question whether "help" in that folder is "Input".

What I really need is that if you select "help" goes to page #1 created is not going to select another to page #2 created.

if the selected component is "help" goes to page # 1
if the selected component is not "help" goes to page # 2

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Components]
Name: "help"; Description: "Help File";

[Code]
var
  CustomPageID: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CustomPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Caption', 
    'Description', 'SubCaption', False, 'NewFolderName');
  CustomPage.Add('Input');
  // store your custom page ID to further use in the ShouldSkipPage event
  CustomPageID := CustomPage.ID;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // initialize result to not skip any page (not necessary, but safer)
  Result := False;
  // if the page that is asked to be skipped is your custom page, then...
  if PageID = CustomPageID then
    // if the component is not selected, skip the page
    Result := not IsComponentSelected('help');
end;
```

Comment: How is that sample not doing what you want? It will skip the custom page if the "help" component is not selected.

Comment: @Deanna, there is no skipping of page #2. Err wait, there is no page #2 :-)

Comment: Deanna and TLama, I want is a " if the component is A goes to page # 1 " - " if the component B is going to go to page # 2 ". Excuse my English if I did not understand me, and my little experience.